# How to find a discrete Morse function on this simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have a graph called partition graph. This graph gives rise to a simplicial complex called box complex $B_{edge}$. Since this simplicial complex is too big and studying the topological features of it is too difficult I want to simplify this simplicial complex using a discrete Morse function.

**Definition**.
Every vertex of a **partition graph** $\mathcal{P}(3^3)$ is a partition of $\{1,2, ..., 9 \}$ into $3$ cells of size $3$. Two vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if the intersection of each cell of $u$ with each cell of $v$ is nonempty.

This graph is vertex- edge- arc transitive.

**Definition**. The **box complex $B_{edge}(G)$** of a graph $G$ is a simplicial complex which vertices are the directed edges of $G$; that is, ordered pairs $(u,v)$ with $\{u,v\}\in E$. The simplices of this box complex are subsets of edge sets of complete bipartite subgraphs of $G$, where the edges are oriented from the first shore to the second shore.
\begin{align*}
    B_{edge}(G):=&\{ \overrightarrow{F} \subset A'\times A'': \varnothing \neq A',A'' \subset V,\\
    &A'\cap A''=\varnothing, G[A',A'']\ \text{is complete}\}
\end{align*}
I want to find a discrete Morse function on the box complex $B_{edge}(\mathcal{P}(3^3))$. A function with less critical simplicies is better.